# python-tk package is not recognized?

Tags: python

I've got a small program I've written in python (2.7.3) that I'm moving over to another box.

However, when executing this line:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

I get this error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 42, in <module>
    raise ImportError, str(msg) + ', please install the python-tk package'
ImportError: /usr/lib/libtk8.5.so.0: invalid ELF header, please install the python-tk package
```

However, it looks to me that python-tk is installed.

```
python-tk is already the newest version.
```

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`sudo apt-get remove tk8.5`

and

`sudo apt-get install tk8.5`